# Laravel login with username/email and password

Tags: laravel

I have a normal login function in my laravel project,

```
   public function login(Request $request) {
       $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

       if (!Auth::attempt($credentials))
           return redirect(route('public.login'))->with('error', 'Invalid credentials'); // KO

       $user = Auth::user();
   
       // OK
       if ($user->hasRole('admin'))
           return redirect(route('admin.home'))->with('toast', 'Welcome, ' . $user->name . '!');
       
       $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
           return redirect(route('dashboard.home'))->with('toast', 'Welcome, ' . $user->name . '!');
   }
```

Now I can login just with email and password
I want to login with username and password also.

How can I edit my function to do this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing "email" with "username"?

Answer (score 0):

Update your `User` model to implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` contract. This typically involves adding the use `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait and implementing the required methods. Your model might look something like this:

```
// app/Models/User.php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    // ... other model code ...

    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'username'; // or 'email' depending on your preference
    }
}
```